# Xbee S2 API Data Packets dropping out

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, xbee

I made a setup which consists of 3 Zigbee's, 2 routers(Zigbee S2C's) and 1 coordinator(Zigbee S2). The routers are each connected to arduino nano which collects data from 2 FSR's and an IMU(frame type: zigbee transmit request and packet size 46 bytes) and sends it to the Coordinator attached to an arduino UNO. All the Xbees are in API mode 2 and working at a baud rate of 115200. I am using a library called "Simple Zigbee Library" to send all the collected data to the Coordinator. The collection and sending of data works fine except that there are packets lost in the way. The nano's sample data at a frequency of around 25Hz independently. The coordinator tries to read the data send from the zigbees(using the library of course) in every loop, but unfortunately, it seems to receive only around 40-45 samples.(Should have been 25*2=50 samples total from the 2 xbees). Can anybody suggest why this is happening. I need as less data loss as possible for my setup to achieve its motive. Any kind of help is appreciated.

P.S: It may be important to mention that the coordinator is reading the data only from one xbee in each loop.

[[[As can be seen from the "Source" heading in this image of data received by the coordinator, "19" and "106" are addresses of the routers. Data drop is intermittent]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sw9V.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sw9V.png)

```
    void setup() 
{
// Start the serial ports ...
Serial.begin( 9600 );
while( !Serial ){;}  // Wait for serial port (for Leonardo only). 
xbeeSerial.begin( 9600 );
// ... and set the serial port for the XBee radio.
xbee.setSerial( xbeeSerial );
// Set a non-zero frame id to receive Status packets.
xbee.setAcknowledgement(true); 
}

void loop() 
{
// Each SimpleZigBeeRadio instance contains two 
// SimpleZigBeePacket instances, one for storing incoming
// messages and one for preparing outgoing messages.
// This example will not send any messages to the network.
// Rather, the coordinator will receive messages and display
// the contents to the hardware serial port.

// While data is waiting in the XBee serial port ...
while( xbee.available() )
{
// ... read the data.
xbee.read();
// If a complete message is available, display the contents
if( xbee.isComplete() ){
Serial.print("\nIncoming Message: ");
printPacket( xbee.getIncomingPacketObject() );

}
}


delay(10); // Small delay for stability
// That's it! The coordinator is ready to go.
}



 // Function for printing the complete contents of a packet //

void printPacket(SimpleZigBeePacket & p)
{
Serial.print( START, HEX );
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print( p.getLengthMSB(), HEX );
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print( p.getLengthLSB(), HEX );
Serial.print(' ');
// Frame Type and Frame ID are stored in Frame Data
uint8_t checksum = 0;
for( int i=0; i<p.getFrameLength(); i++){
Serial.print( p.getFrameData(i), HEX );
Serial.print(' ');
checksum += p.getFrameData(i); 
}
// Calculate checksum based on summation of frame bytes
checksum = 0xff - checksum;
Serial.print(checksum, HEX );
Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: If transmits aren't coordinated, perhaps CCA,  clear channel assessment, is wasting a bunch of time.  Perhaps have a transmit order, perhaps assign time slots?

Comment: I believe using the Xbee in API mode is supposed to take care of that. The routers are getting Acknowledgements from the Coordinator for most of the packets. The packets not acknowledged are getting dropped. I tried to decrease the frame size ,reduce the payload and remove all delays, still the data drop is present. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you turn off one router and let the other send as fast as it can?  Ie what throughput does it get, does it drop packets, etc

Comment: On working just with 1 router, I am not getting packets dropped. The nano is sending  25  packets and all of them are getting received by the UNO.

Comment: But try upping the rate of that one router (eg to 30, 40, 50, 60, 70... per second) and see how fast you can run without dropouts.  For example, if it runs ok at 60 or 70 samples/second through 1 router but only 40-45 with 2 then some interference between the two routers might be involved